# Laravel pluck didnot return sort array as database

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 5.8 for my project. I want to get an array with 'id' of table. So I use [Laravel Collection - pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) for this problem.

This is my database.

[image]

```
App\User::pluck('id')->all()
```

=> [ 3, 1, 4, 2]

Why doesn't it return [1, 2, 3, 4]??
So I tried `App\User::all()->pluck('id')`
Wow, it returned [1, 2, 3, 4].

Why does the second work??

Comment: Weird... I can't replicate locally. Also, `App\User::pluck()` is not the same method as `App\User::all()->pluck()`; the first is a `Builder` instance, the second is a `Collection`. They both have a `pluck()` method, and *should* mirror results, but yeah, technically different methods.

Comment: Both \App\User::pluck('id')->all() and \App\User::all() pluck run the same query and return the result in whatever order the database decides to return them in. The difference is that in the first example the results are immediately made into an array, which has no default ordering, where the second creates a collection first which orders the values by id ASC, then pluck converts that to an array and keeps the ordering the same

Comment: @AlecJoy Since `App\User::` initializes the query, it *should* apply the default sorting (ordering by primary key); doesn't matter if it's followed by `pluck()` or `all()`. Something's off here. The ordering it's returning is matching the order that would be applied if it was using `email` as the sort key. ("B", "L", "O", "Y")

Comment: @TimLewis I turned the query log on in my own program to see what actual SQL query is being run and in both cases it was just select `id` from `users`; Running that query against my won database through php my admin returned the results in a similarly strange order as OP experienced. So does doing a raw select.

Comment: @AlecJoy That is very bizarre... You might be in a better position to help debug this then. I don't use the default `Auth` login in Laravel, so my `App\User` and `users` migration/table are vastly different. But again, double check your "similarly strange order"; I'd bet it's using `email` as the sort key in one query, but id as the sort in the other (even if it doesn't explicitly say that's what's going on).

Comment: @TimLewis Okay I think I actually see the different here, the raw query is returning them in the random order but when Eloquent converts them to model instances it puts them in the correct order, which then gets ->plucked. The pluck method skips turning them into objects since you only want an column values. I don't know how SQL chose that order, it's not by email as the order of email is k, a, g, s etc

Comment: @AlecJoy I still don't think it's random, unless the order changes with each test. Look at the order they said `App\User::pluck('id')->all()` returns: `[3, 1, 4, 2]`. This directly matches the emails: id of email "B" is 3, id of email "L" is 1, id of email "O" is 4 and id of email "Y" is 2. I don't know why `email` would be used, all it has is a `unique()` key, but regardless, I'm not sure this is actually going anywhere. If you think you have it figured out, post an answer for them :)

Comment: @TimLewis was just about to say see my longer answer haha, It may well be that in their case SQL is deciding to order them by email but that isn't reliable. SQL behaves strangely if you don't give it an orderBy clause, it returns records in whatever order it decides and I don't know if there is any actual way to determine what that order is but the order is unreliable.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in the results of these two queries is caused by how eloquent interprets you wanting to use the data. In both cases the query that gets run against your database is an unconstrained `select` statement, if you run the pluck first it only selects the `id` field, if you run the all() first it selects all fields.

The result that gets returned from mysql has no default order. If you do not specify an order in your SQL query, [SQL decides the order the records are returned in and it is inconsistent and non-determinant](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775#5775)

So in the first example the results are returned in whatever order MySQL decides and immediately added to an array because that's all you asked for. The order of the values of the array is the same as whatever gets returned from the SQL query.

In the second example, Eloquent turns the values it gets back from the database into instances of `User::class` and puts them into a collection. When an eloquent collection contains model instances, it's sorted by id unless you specify otherwise. You then perform the pluck method which grabs just the `id` and keeps them in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `orderBy` method before the `pluck` method you can sort an array. Please have a look at the below example.

```
App\User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
App\User::select('id')->orderBy('id')->get();
```